# How to identify and count unique chars in a stringstream

Tags: c++, containers, stringstream

The function reads each line of a file. (The chars represent political parties.) The first token is ignored but function must identify and count the instances of the subsequent chars. There will be at least two unique chars per line, but there can be more. The chars are unknown at runtime. An input file might look like this:

```
district1 D D R R D
district2 D G R R R I
district3 I D D R D D 
district4 R R I
```

How do I apply streamstream to identify, read, count individual char in a line? I will use these values later in the code to calculate some ratios.

```
Map<string, double> gerrymanderingRatios(string file) {
    Map<string, double> gerryMap;
    ifstream file_in(file);

    if (file_in) {
        string line, ignoreMe;
        stringstream ss;
        while (file_in >> ignoreMe, getline(file_in, line)) {
            /* ignore first token and count instances of each
            char in the line. */
        }
        file_in.close();

        /* calculate ratios for "political party" (char)
        and insert into the map. */
    }
    return gerryMap;
```

The result will be a map; keys are parties (char) and values are ratios, i.e { {"D", 0.4543}, {"R", 1.0323}, {"I", 0.343} }

Comment: One method you can do is to create an array of 256 integers that represent ASCII characters that is zero initialized. With this array all you have to do is then increment each character by doing something like `parties[char]++;` Next in the map simply iterate through the array and add all characters to the map that have a value greater than 0 and their ratio as count at that location / total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, making use of exceptions to know if a symbol is already in the map or not. Editing your code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<map>
#include<stdexcept>

using namespace std;

map<string, double> gerrymanderingRatios(string file) {
    map<string, int> countMap;
    map<string, double> gerryMap;
    ifstream file_in(file);

    if (file_in) {
        string line, ignoreMe, ch;
        int total = 0;
        while (file_in >> ignoreMe, getline(file_in, line)) {
            /* ignore first token and count instances of each
            char in the line. */
            stringstream ss(line);
            while(ss >> ch) {
                try {
                    countMap.at(ch)++;
                } catch(const out_of_range& oor) {
                    countMap[ch] = 1;
                }
                total++;
            }            
        }
        file_in.close();

        // print the final count for each element
        map<string, int>::iterator it;
        for (it = countMap.begin(); it != countMap.end(); it++ ) {
            cout << it->first
               << ':'
               << it->second
               << endl;
        }

        /* calculate ratios for "political party" (char)
        and insert into the map. */

        //calculate ratios
        for (it = countMap.begin(); it != countMap.end(); it++ ) {
            gerryMap[it->first] = (double)it->second / total;
        }

        //print total ratios
        cout << "ratios" << endl;
        map<string, double>::iterator dit;
        for (dit = gerryMap.begin(); dit != gerryMap.end(); dit++ ) {
          cout << dit->first 
               << ':'
               << dit->second
               << endl;
        }

    }
    return gerryMap;
}

int main() {
    map<string, double> ratiomap = gerrymanderingRatios("example.txt");

    //do whatever you need with the ratios

    return 0;
}
```

The relevant part is this:

```
while(ss >> ch) {
    try {
        countMap.at(ch)++;
    } catch(const out_of_range& oor) {
        countMap[ch] = 1;
    }
    total++;
}
```

`countMap.at(ch)` will throw an `out_of_range` exception if the key `ch` is not in the map. So I can try to increment the value, but if the exception is thrown, it's added instead with a count of 1.
Notice that I have introduced a `map<string, int> countMap` to keep the individual counts of each key using integers, and used yours `map<string, double> gerryMap` at the end when I calculate the ratios.

Comment: Note that [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will create the element if it is missing and value initialize it. (for non-class types this is zero initialization) This means that your relevant part can be simplified substantially by just doing `++countMap[ch]`. This is faster, too, because it does not rely on exceptions for non-exceptional cases.